# Plugin 'maven-clean-plugin:' not found in Intellij IDE

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin

I added the following in my `pom.xml`.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pom-manual-clean</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Intellij IDE complains that:

```
Plugin 'maven-clean-plugin:' not found
```

Also note that in the auto complete also it does not appear.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need to add an explicit execution for a maven-clean-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I am learning maven and I tried it for learning purposes

Comment: Ok. That's just fine. Have you tried to run your build on plain command and no frim within your IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I am trying out things from the pom. Is there an equivalent of what I am trying to do from the command line?

Comment: The most important part here is to start from plain command line...just to eliminate a supplemtal source of issues out of the equation... Try on command line first... if everything works than import that project into your IDE ... Also check if your IDE is the most recent version etc (Java, Maven etc.)

Comment: This plugin must exist in your local Maven repository - then IDe will not report this error. You can trigger download of the plugin by executing one of the maven goals from this plugin. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

Add element `<version>`, like:

```xml
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
```

*Tested with Maven 3.9.6 and IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Community Edition).*